# XPath - select anchor after some text

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I'd like to fetch data from this sample code:

```
<div id="text">

(sd) <a href="http://example.com/somefiledfs.flv">http://example.com/somefiledfs.flv</a>
 - 380 kbps 
 - <a href='/player.swf?config={"clip":{"url":"http://example.com/somefiledfs.flv"}'>Watch</a><br>

(576p) <a href="http://example.com/hgyj.mp4">http://example.com/hgyj.mp4</a>
 - 780 kbps 
 - <a href='/player.swf?config={"clip":{"url":"http://example.com/hgyj.mp4"}'>Watch</a><br>

</div>
```

I'd like to get it as:

```
sd - http://example.com/somefiledfs.flv

576p - http://example.com/hgyj.mp4
```

and so on.

Could sb help? I've beed trying to use "//div[@id='text']/a" and ancestor/preceding but I can't work it out.

Comment: I think It's better to use regular expressions here.

Comment: So please give an example of working code.

Comment: @ValeryStatichny It is almost always NOT better to use regular expressions to parse and manipulate HTML.

Comment: @MikeBrant, In this situation XPATH can't provide us functionality that we expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working PHP snippet, basically loop over all links then check the previous node if it matches `sd|576p` (extend more formats here if needed...)

```
<?php 
$html = <<<HTML
<div id="text">
  (sd) <a href="http://example.com/somefiledfs.flv">http://example.com/somefiledfs.flv</a>   
    - 380 kbps 
    - <a href='/player.swf?config={"clip":{"url":"http://example.com/somefiledfs.flv"}'>Watch</a><br>

  (576p) <a href="http://example.com/hgyj.mp4">http://example.com/hgyj.mp4</a>
    - 780 kbps 
    - <a href='/player.swf?config={"clip":{"url":"http://example.com/hgyj.mp4"}'>Watch</a><br>

</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$as = $xpath->query("//div[@id='text']/a");

foreach ($as as $a) {
  $prev = $a->previousSibling->nodeValue;

  if (preg_match("/sd|576p/", $prev, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[0]." - ".$a->nodeValue."\r\n";
  }
}
?>
```

here's a link to the snippet: https://eval.in/173038